# Excel column difference

Tags: excel

Sheet 1 has some information in as well as a serial number for each product. This was completed in June 2012.

Sheet 2 has had the information modified, as new products have come in, this has been updated from June 2012 until now.

I want to find out the new items which have been added without doing it manually, I know I will need to do it with serial numbers but how?

Thanks.

P.s. I have office 2003 if this helps.

Comment: try `vlookup`. you can look up serial numbers in sheet1 against serial numbers in sheet2.  where you get an error statement against the serial numbers in sheet2, those are your new products :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional formatting to highlight the cells that are not new, and you can then sort the column. So you would specify the column in sheet 1 with serial numbers and then the same column in sheet 2 and check for duplicates.

This tutorial should help:
[Excel 2003 Conditional Formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/locate-duplicates-by-using-conditional-formatting-HA001136616.aspx)

Hope this helps.